# How to check duplicate text in a single column mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have thousand records in my `ps_product_lang` table.in this table i have `description_short` column.it contain some descriptions.

**Problem**
in some rows,this description duplicated in `description_short` column.i want to check `description_short` column text.if column text duplicate like below,i want to update column with correct text.

eg: 
`ps_product_lang` table

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id       | description_short                            |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|        1 | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum |
|          | is simply dummy text.                        |
|        2 | Contrary to popular belief                   |
+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.` is duplicated for id =1.is there a way to check it and update `description_short` column.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of the REPLACE command [Link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)

Example which may help you:

```
SELECT id,description_short,
REPLACE(description_short,'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.','Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.') 
FROM publisher 
WHERE description_short='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.';
```